How to map USB inputs in Docker?
I'm having trouble mapping USB input for use in the Docker cointeiner. I want to use my KinectV2 which is connected to the USB port, I've tried :
xhost +
docker run --rm -it --user ros -v /dev:/dev --device-cgroup-rule='c *:* rmw' -v /run/udev:/run/udev --ipc=host pu:v4 bash
and inside Docker when I run lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
The Kinect, outside the docker when I run lsusb, is seen as:
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045e:02c4 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Sensor
Below is my Dockerfile:
FROM osrf/ros:noetic-desktop

ARG ROS_DISTRO=noetic

ARG USERNAME=ros
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
 && useradd -s /bin/bash --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
 && mkdir /home/$USERNAME/.config && chown $USER_UID:$USER_GID /home/$USERNAME/.config


# Set up sudo
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y sudo \
 && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME\
 && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*



# install ros packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y &&\
   apt-get install python3-pip -y && \
   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config  -y && \
   apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev -y && \        
   apt-get install libturbojpeg0-dev -y && \ 
   apt-get install libglfw3-dev -y && \         
   apt-get install libopenni2-dev -y && \
   apt-get install git -y && \
   apt-get install ros-noetic-catkin -y
        
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y \
   && apt install -y \
   libusb-1.0-0-dev \
   libturbojpeg \
   libturbojpeg0-dev \
   libjpeg-turbo8-dev \
   libglfw3-dev \
   libopenni2-dev \
   freeglut3-dev \
   uuid-dev \
   libsdl2-dev \
   usbutils \
   python3-catkin-tools \
   python3-rosdep \
   alsa-utils \
   ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-ros-core \
   ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-vision-opencv \
   ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-nodelet-core \
   ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-perception-pcl \
   ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-compressed-depth-image-transport \
   ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-compressed-image-transport \
   ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-geometry \
   ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-depth-image-proc \
   python3-opencv \
   udev \
   nano \
   && apt-get clean

WORKDIR /home

RUN git clone https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2.git

WORKDIR /home/libfreenect2

RUN mkdir build &&\
   cd build && \
   cmake .. \
   -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/freenect2 \
   -DENABLE_CXX11=ON && \
   make && \
   make install && \
   mkdir -p /etc/udev/rules.d/ && \
   cp /home/libfreenect2/platform/linux/udev/90-kinect2.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/

WORKDIR /home

RUN mkdir -p kinect_ws/src

WORKDIR /home/kinect_ws/src

RUN git clone https://github.com/paul-shuvo/iai_kinect2_opencv4.git

WORKDIR /home/kinect_ws/src/iai_kinect2_opencv4

RUN rosdep install -r -y --from-paths .

WORKDIR /home/kinect_ws

I'm having trouble mapping USB input for use in the Docker cointeiner. I want to use my KinectV2 which is connected to the USB port, I've tried
xhost +
`docker run --rm -it --user ros -v /dev:/dev --device-cgroup-rule='c : rmw' -v /run/udev:/run/udev --ipc=host pu:v4 bash

A container doesn't normally have access to host devices.  If you need access to the host display (you mention xhost), the host IPC namespace, and host hardware devices, would it be easier to run this process directly on the host, without any of Docker's isolation features?

Ros noetic only works for ubuntu 20.04, I'm currently using 22.04 and didn't want to downgrade. Not to mention that the kinect calibration tool works with ros noetic and older distros.
